# Extract R^2 (R-squared) value for each regression grouped by a factor

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I'm wondering if there is a way to extract R2 for each regression equation.

```
d <- data.frame(
  state = rep(c('NY', 'CA'), 10),
  year = rep(1:10, 2),
  response= rnorm(20)
)

library(plyr)
models <- dlply(d, "state", function(df) 
  lm(response ~ year, data = df))

ldply(models, coef)
l_ply(models, summary, .print = TRUE)
```

I tried

```
l_ply(models, summary$r.squared, .print = TRUE)
```

But this throws the following error message

```
Error in summary$r.squared : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Comment: Does this work for you:  `ldply(models, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)`?

Comment: The error is due to the fact that summary is a function and you can not use the `$` operator on a function.  In addition, the second argument of `l_ply` has to be a function, which it is not in your case. For the correct solution, see Frank...

Comment: Thanks @Frank for your helpful comment. Would you like to change your comment to answer. Can you help me to get both coefficients and R2 through one command. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this to get the R squared value and the coefficients:

```
ldply(models, function(x) {r.sq <- summary(x)$r.squared
                           intercept <- summary(x)$coefficients[1]
                           beta <- summary(x)$coefficients[2]
                           data.frame(r.sq, intercept, beta)})
#  state        r.sq intercept        beta
#1    CA 0.230696121 0.4915617 -0.12343947
#2    NY 0.003506936 0.1971734 -0.01227367
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the [broom](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/index.html) package for converting statistical analysis objects into data.frames and `dplyr` for `bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr) ; library(broom)
cbind(
  state = attr(models, "split_labels"),
  bind_rows(lapply(models, function(x) cbind(
    intercept = tidy(x)$estimate[1],
    beta = tidy(x)$estimate[2],
    glance(x))))
)

  state  intercept        beta  r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma statistic   p.value df    logLik      AIC      BIC deviance df.residual
1    CA 0.38653551 -0.05459205 0.01427426   -0.10894146 1.434599 0.1158477 0.7423473  2 -16.68252 39.36505 40.27280 16.46460           8
2    NY 0.09028554 -0.08462742 0.04138985   -0.07843642 1.287909 0.3454155 0.5729312  2 -15.60387 37.20773 38.11549 13.26968           8
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
sapply(models, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
     CA      NY 
0.05639 0.23751
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try

```
> typeof( summary )
[1] "closure"
```

you see that 'summary' is a function.  You are trying to access a field of the result, but `summary$r.squared` tries to access that field on the function / closure.

Using an anonymous function,

```
> l_ply( models, function( m ) summary( m )$r.squared, .print = TRUE )
[1] 0.2319583
[1] 0.01295825
```

will work and print the result.  However, you say that you want to "extract the result".  This probably means that you want to *use* the result and not just print it.

From the documentation of `l_ply` (which you'll get by typing `?l_ply` at the R prompt):

> For each element of a list, apply function and discard results.

(So this function will not work if you want to hang on to the result.)

Using the standard `sapply`/`lapply` will result in

```
> a <- sapply( models, function( t ) summary( t )$r.squared )
> a
        CA         NY 
0.23195825 0.01295825 
> typeof( a )
[1] "double"
> is.vector( a )
[1] TRUE
> # or alternatively
> l <- lapply( models, function( t ) summary( t )$r.squared )
> l
$CA
[1] 0.2319583

$NY
[1] 0.01295825
> typeof( l )
[1] "list"
```

Either one should work -- pick whichever result (vector or list) is easier to use for what you want to do. (If unsure, just pick `sapply`.)

(Or, if you want to use functions from the `plyr` package, `laply`, `ldply`, and `llply` seem to work too. But I've never used that package, so I can't say what's best.)